# What do you call the stage in a woman's life before she is a mother?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call the stage in a woman's life before she has a child? Un-motherhood? Something else?

What are you doing with your last days of #### before you adopt a baby?

Looking for a noun, hopefully something that isn't parenting centric.. child-free, unmotherhood, etc. Something perhaps like adolescence...

Comment: There's no way that such a word wouldn't be parenting-focused if it's a period that's defined as "the time before parenthood"

Comment: the word is ***freedom***

Comment: @juhasz that's fair.  Someone I think suggested maidenhood but to me that suggests an unmarried woman or a virgin.... what if this woman is married, but just child-free.

Comment: I didn't want to get into a political discussion, but do note that defining a life (and especially a woman's life) as pre-parental and post-parental may annoy some people (such as those who chose not to have children - they probably don't think of their whole post-pubescent life as "pre-parental").  I don't necessarily find it offensive, I just don't have a word for you.

Comment: Before she ever gives birth to a first child, a woman is said to be "a nullipara", no matter her age.   Although the word comes to mind, it wouldn't be an answer to your question because It only defines a woman's obstetric status and is not exactly a term for a stage in her life. Then again, a woman who never bore a child can always adopt one and be a mother.

Comment: Child-free years?

Comment: Also @Juhasz That could be "pre-parenthood" then.

Comment: Why the down votes? Too bad.

Comment: What are you doing with your last days of **sleep** before adopting/giving birth...

Answer (score 0):

The term is *Maiden* from the German which went to become madchen [mit die umluat].

This means an as yet sexually inexperienced young women. Ones Aunt who never married is referred to as a *maiden aunt*. That she never had sex was the implication back so long ago.

That they were interested in such experience is evident from the Burma-shave rhyme;

The answer to a maiden's prayers

is not a chin of stubbled hairs.

Comment: The question is less about getting married and more about having a child.

Comment: I think it's still the correct answer. "Maiden" means "sexually inexperienced woman", after all, hence the old trifecta of "Maiden, Mother, Crone". This answer does have a lot of irrelevant cruft in it, though.

Comment: A perfectly cromulent point. Wish I had made it.